# Make td smaller than its content?

Tags: html, css

Is there any way at all to make a table-cell smaller than its contents using purely css, and without altering the DOM?
Setting the width of a td to smaller than its child only makes it as large as its child for me. I also tried adding table-layout:fixed to the table but that didn't make any difference.

**HTML:**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><div/></td>
    <td class="mycell"><div/></td>
    <td><div/></td>
</tr>
```

**CSS:**

```
table {
    table-layout:fixed;
}
td {
    border:3px solid black;
}
div {
    border:3px solid red;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
.mycell {
 width:20px;
```

**jsfiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/clox/EzKNy/

Comment: Maybe set display: inline; for the `div`?

Comment: @Clox if jomikr answer was solved your problem, please accept that as answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. But you have to use the value `max-width` instead. So it reads:

```
.mycell {
    max-width: 20px;
}
```

Comment: This, however, implies that the content of the cell will overflow to the next cell.

Comment: You can hide the overflow with `.mycell {max-width: 20px; overflow: hidden;}`

Answer (score 0):

If you make inner div position absolute and outter td position relative, it will take inner div out of normal flow.

http://jsfiddle.net/EzKNy/2/

```
td {
    border:3px solid black;
    position:relative;
}
div {
    border:3px solid red;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
}
```